# How to use cp (Copy) command in system function in native C code on Android

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk

I want to copy file from on directory to another in my native C program.
I tried using `system` function but it's not working.

I tried this code in native code of Android

```
int result = system("cp /mnt/test /Download/"); // It's not working
```

This system function returns `256` (error code) integer value. So we can say system function is working in Android.  I also installed BusyBox so I can use the `cp` command also.

If I execute directly `cp /mnt/test /Download/` command then it's working fine.

So what is problem here in `system` function.   Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

*system()* function returns non-zero to indicate that a command processor is available, or zero if none is available. You can use macros defined in *sys/wait.h* to analize the return value. Also *system()* in fact calls *fork()* syscall and *execl()* with default (*sh*) command interperter. So if your programm exits immidiately after calling *system()* consider using *waitpid()* function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but let me know how can i Solve my this issue and whats problem in my code.

Comment: You do not need to call `waitpid` after `system`, it does this itself

Comment: Indeed `system()` doesn't return until the child process is ended, my bad. I cannot see any apparent problem in your code but `system()` sets `errno` on error, you could print it (or even use `strerror()`).

Comment: @well-wisher thanks for Your kind Response LEt me know how can i use strerror() function in this code to trace my error in cp command

Comment: Simply add `if (errno) perror("system");` after `system` call. `errno` variable defined in `errno.h`, `perror` function defined in `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a path issue.  Try specifying the full path to the busybox "cp" command, like so:

```
int result = system("/path/to/bbdir/cp /mnt/test /Download/");
```

I'm not sure where busybox keeps its files, so just change "/path/to/bbdir" to reflect your actual busybox path.

Comment: I also Checked that one. i installed in /system/bin/ so i take full path also. /system/bin/cp /mnt/test /Download

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question stems from the fact that there is no "cp" function call in glibc.

If you only need to copy files, just open two files and start copying ;-)
The textbook examples for implementing cp usually start by byte-by-byte copy, then move to block copy and finally implement a file copy using mmap().

If you need other functionality like preserving symlinks and such, the code will quickly increase in complexity.

In that case, it might be tempting to want to use system().
However, on Android, there are only a few systems that ship with busybox.
Most systems still ship with the original Android 'toolbox'. This one is very very limited in what it provides and can do.

By the way, if 'cp' doesn't work and you are sure you have busybox, try '/bin/busybox cp' instead.